# How to go back to main thread?

Tags: ollydbg, thread

I was analyzing a sample and the function `CreateRemoteThread` is called with `dwCreationFlag = 0`, so the created thread starts immediately after creation.
OllyDbg jumps to beginning of the new thread. I analyze the new thread and at the end of that, it calls `RtlExitUserThread` and the thread is terminated.

To visualize, you can consider the following:

```
  PUSH EAX                              ; dwCreationFlag = 0
     .
     .
     .
  CALL DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-28]           ; CreateRemoteThread
     .
  (lines which I would also like to analyze)
```

As I described, the new thread starts and it ends with a call to `RtlExitUserThread` but I would like to analyze the lines after the call to `RtlExitUserThread`.

How can I go back to the main thread, because there was a lot of lines to analyze (after the call to `CreateRemoteThread`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click within the Disassembler window -> *Select thread* -> Click *Main thread*

Here is an image for reference.
[image]